# Where exactly should I put ehcache.xml in my project?

Tags: java, ehcache

I've recently began using EHCache for caching purposes. I know, how to use it in Java code, but I'm still not sure about the configuration file.

So, I have an ear project, that includes several war modules. If all these modules use ehcache, should I put a copy of ehcache.xml in WEB-INF for each module, or put it somewhere in ear file itself (META-INF maybe?)

Also, it's not clear from the documentation, whether or not all these modules will use the same cache instance? The application is deployed at glassfish, will EHCache run the same cache for each module in ear, or each module will get his own singleton instance when used like this:

```
CacheManager singleton = CacheManager.create();
```

Answer (score 3):

1. According to **ehcache.xml** file. There is no rule where you will put this file, but if you are working on a big project I presume that you have several profiles (e.g. for QA, DEV, PROD). As ehcache may differ depending on profile (for example, if you have ehcache jms replication enabled) you can have different JMS Server IPs set up there or amount of objects in cache regions may differ, so I suggest to put in where you have profile-dependent file (e.g. web.xml, log4j.properties). Then if you have context configuration in a separate xml file like:

> ```
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>     <param-value>/WEB-INF/context-config.xml</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```

then you may add in that **context-config.xml** file:

> ```
> <import resource="context-config.xml"/>
> ```

That **context-config.xml** file may contain description of cacheManager bean, that you will be able to Autowire where do you need it. So the **context-config.xml** may look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

        <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

Answering your second question. From my example, it will depend on how you will define this bean, you can define it as a singleton and then you will have only one instance of cacheManager or you can leave the instantiation to Spring. 
In my opinion, you can autowire cacheManager to the class with general logic for cache invalidation or cache "creation" and that will make a lot of sense. Hope that I helped you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hard and fast rule for putting in your ehcache configuration file.
But, personally I keep my ehcache config file with all the other configuration
and properties file.

For example, I will store the path to my ehcache config xml file in some static final variable, (helps in keeping the path configurable )

```
private static final String EHCACHE_CONFIG = "<path to this file>/ehcache.xml";
```

And then when I initialize the cache manager, I give in the path to config 
file as a parameter

```
CacheManager manager = new CacheManager(EHCACHE_CONFIG);
```